# tor is not working in ubuntu 14.06

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu, tor-install

at the first i installed tor by the Ubuntu software , and i couldn't start tor , it always shows a failure saying that if I'm under attack or if I'm having a problem with the connection , definitely none of them does exist , the second time i downloaded the tor browser normally from tor project website , and i run the written commands on the terminal , tor browser didn't work neither . [image]

Answer (score 1):

You're in the wrong directory.

The screenshot shows you running the command from your home directory (`~`) but the file exists in your Downloads directory (`~/Downloads`).

*Either*:
run `cd Downloads` then `tar vJxf tor-browser-linux64-7.0a2-hardened-All.tar.xz`
*Or*:
run `tar vJxf ~/Downloads/tor-browser-linux64-7.0a2-hardened-All.tar.xz`

You could also just open the file by double clicking on it in the file manager and choose to extract it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your `torbrowser-launcher` package (the new version fixes the bug that lead to that "I'm under attack or if I'm having a problem with the connection" error message), to do that write in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install torbrowser-launcher
```

Comment: There is no indication that the OP uses torbrowser-launcher at all. So your answer would probably not help the user.

Answer (score 0):

Just download tor browser from website using other web browser. Extract the file at any directory and click the extracted folder. Find the app image in the folder and run it by just clicking. You don't have to use terminal if you do this. I hope this would help you.